# How is the world safe at the end of The Gone World?

Tags: the-gone-world

In the book *The Gone World*, in the end, we see that

> Courtney is alive.

How is the world safe though? Libra was still launched, right? Meaning they could still find the Terminus and bring it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the book, I don't think that

> the world is safe necessarily, just that the chances of the terminus happening are less than 100%. When the Libra crash landed back on earth, it carried with it the information about where the terminus' planet of origin was in the minds of its crew. The theory was that as long as someone alive knew where the planet was, that knowledge would spread back to people that would try to revisit the planet, bringing about the Terminus.

Libra was indeed still launched, but

> it never came back and crash landed on earth. That whole sequence of events was an IFT that collapsed when all of the crew on the Libra died. If a traveler dies in an IFT, then from the perspective of Terra Firma, the traveler(s) just never return. This is the same thing that would have happened if Moss had died in any of the IFTs she was traveling to.

Comment: Ah yes, the terra firma's Libra has been destroyed. That's right! Thanks.